# How do I display an attribute on product view page in magento 2

Tags: php, attributes, magento2, price

I am trying to display some attributes on the product view page on a magento 2 website. However i am not able to get the values to echo onto the page. I have tried using

```
$block->getData('price')
```

and

```
$block->getAttributeText('name')
```

I am trying to call upon the price value and also a custom text attribute and display/use via phtml file.

Appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();
echo $_product->getPrice();
echo $_product->getAttributeText('color');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($singleproductdata['entity_id']);
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
       foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

                echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();   
                echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);   

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick option it is to choose a template with in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml and add the following code.  Otherwise you can build your own block and get it from the the catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?php
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your-att-code');
    if ($attribute)
    {
        $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        echo $attr_value;
    }
?>
```